# How to enable Dropwizard Metrics in Play 2.5 HikariCP?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

HikariCP database connection pool used in Play 2.5 [supports Dropwizard Metrics](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics). The recommended approach is to use `HikariConfig.setMetricRegistry(MetricRegistry)`, but Play does not seem to be using Dependency Injection for HikariConfig.  Is there another option to set MetricRegistry on Play HikariCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the HikaryDatasource using

```
@Singleton
class InitMetricRegistry @Inject () (@NamedDatabaseProvider("default") val defaultDB: Database){
  val ds: HikariDataSource = defaultDB.dataSource.asInstanceOf[HikariDataSource]
  ds.setMetricRegistry(???)
}
```

To initialize the metrics on startup use an eager binding
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings

Comment: Thanks. In fact, this is what I ended up doing yesterday, I will post my solution (in Java) as a separate answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice job with the Java solution. Enjoy Play.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this using the same approach mentioned by @JonasAnso.  Here is the Java snippet.

```
public class AppInitProcessor {
    @Inject
    public AppInitProcessor(Database db, MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        if (db.getDataSource() instanceof HikariDataSource) {
            HikariDataSource dataSource = ((HikariDataSource) db.getDataSource());
            if (dataSource.getMetricRegistry() == null) {
                dataSource.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppInitProcessor is then bound as an eager singleton from custom Guice module.

```
MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();
// configure MetricsRegistry ...
bind(MetricRegistry.class).toInstance(metrics);
// bind app startup
bind(AppInitProcessor.class).asEagerSingleton();
```